# How can i get the last insert id in the create:: in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

How can i get the last inserted id in the laravel. I am using the given below eloquent way to insert the record

```
OutSideCity::create($Tariff3Data);
```

**How can i get the last insert id for the above query ?**

If i use

```
$FreshTripEntry->save();
```

I can get the Lastinsert id by `$Lastid = $FreshTripEntry->id;`

But how can i get the last insert id for the `OutSideCity::create($Tariff3Data);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this..**

```
$Traiff=OutSideCity::create($Tariff3Data);

$insertedId = $Traiff->id;
```